# can't connect to mysql container from spring-boot Saying "Communications link failure, last packet sent was, docker + spring boot + mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker, jdbc, docker-compose

Trying to connect from spring boot to mysql container inside docker, but not able to.
Here is my docker-compose.yml file, scratching my head whole day, tried everything but still getting
the same error

> Error: Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> tinyurl-app_backend-1  |
> tinyurl-app_backend-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

[[Error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eP6N.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcgZG.png)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: tinyurl_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
  redis_cache:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
  app_backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - springboot-mysql-network
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3366/tinyurl_db
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
      - redis_cache
volumes:
  mysql-data:
networks:
  springboot-mysql-network:
    name: springboot-mysql-network
```

Tried looking online but tried all the solutions but still getting the same error.
I'm new to this docker network stuff and docker-compose.yml stuff.
Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Connections between containers don't use `ports:` at all (and don't require them); you need to use the standard MySQL port 3306 when you set `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` to connect to another container.

Comment: Tried giving the default port of 3306, still getting the same error :-(